# Google Analytic inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

I have an iframe that hosting a third party page (that I build). In that page, I have a Google analytic as below. However, Google analytic is not tracking all the entries...

The third paty page redirects users to different pages depending on different times of the day. Is there anything extra we need to do to implement Google Analytic in an iframe?

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-47306399-1', 'serviceportal.com.au');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 2):

If the page within the `<iframe />` element is on a different domain than the parent page, then you'll run into problems (particularly with older versions of Internet Explorer). The issue is that 3rd party cookies are blocked when there isn't a correct P3P header for every external asset loaded on the page within the `<iframe />` (including the HTML document itself). This will effectively break your tracking code since it relies on 3rd party cookies (i.e. cookies created for domains controlled by Google or whatever other tracking provider you use).

If this is your issue, I've found two fixes.

1. Output proper P3P headers for all assets loaded inside the IFRAME so browsers don't block 3rd party cookies.
2. Use JS to Communicate from the inner-page to the parent-page and then use that communication to trigger tracking pixels from the parent-page.

My guess is that there are other ways to do this as well, this is what has worked for me.

Also, note that you can do as little as change the protocol and the pages will be thought of as on different domains by the browser, so it's generally a good idea to load the IFRAME with a URL starting in `//` rather than `http://` or `https://` so that the protocols of the parent-page and the inner-page will match. This is just if they are on the same domain to start with.

Another note... Please DO NOT just copy/paste any old P3P header value into a production environment just because it makes the "evil eye" go away in IE. Specific P3P header "codes" equate to real privacy policy statements.

Comment: I was going to post the same thing. However, it's not just older versions of IE, it's also Safari and newer versions of Firefox. So a large portion of the web...

Comment: Thanks... What may be a P3P header for the iframe that is loading the form page http://www.discoverychannel.com.au/shows/gold-rush/competition/ ?

Comment: @user3218006 That's a Discovery Channel page and I'll assume you do not have access to edit its source. So you cannot change the headers output by the page (but you also can't put your tracking code on it). In general you can find the headers output by a server in your developer tools (under the Network) tab. You should explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish because I don't think I get it.

Comment: I am building this form competition page as you can see in the i frame of the link... The iframe is hosted by the company I work. ANd discovery is just adding the iframe inside their page. Now in Google analytics I am seeing that not all visitors are tracked. Yes you are right. We do not have abilities to add codes inside Discovery but I have access to the iframe. hmm clear?

Comment: @user3218006 You could try the P3P header method since you have control over the headers your server outputs for the inner-page. I've had it fix tracking cookie problems before.

Answer (score 1):

One of the SEO gurus at my workplace was able to provide me with the solution tips

It was a fact of misamtached server..

The correct code ended up being

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-47544250-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'vserver.com.au']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

Comment: I would verify in IE that the cookies are properly getting set. When I look at the network waterfall, pages coming from your server don't appear to be setting the GA cookies (when IFRAMEd in). Only a `referrer` cookie. This is tested in IE 9 using the IE 8 browser/document mode. When I look at the same resource in Chrome I see all the GA cookies set as expected... This is the issue my answer attempts to fix, which will mess with your reporting because IE is so prevalent. Also if I open your page on its own, the same IE browser configuration correctly sets the GA cookies.